# Is an underlying space of a simplicial complex second countable

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose given a simplicial complex $X$. The underlying space $|X|$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is the union of simplices of $X$. Is $|X|$ is second countable?

I know that any Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is second countable, can I just use the fact that $|X|\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and any subspace of second-countable space is second-countable, so $|X|$ is second-countable? But the topology of $|X|$ is bigger than the topology $|X|$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If the topology is coarser, you cannot rely on the Euclidean topology. It's (IIRC) some weak topology w.r.t. to the finite simplices, right?

Comment: You have to decide for one topology: Either the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R^n$, or the topology coherent with the covering of $|X|$ by its simplices. If the latter, than $|X|$ need not even be first-countable.

Comment: @StefanHamcke: No, we topologize $X$ by declaring a subset $A$ of $X$ is closed in $X$ iff $A\cap\sigma$ is closed in $\sigma$ for each simplex $\sigma\in X$. So, with this topology, $X$ is not second countable?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: The topology is finer, not coarser. We topologize $|X|$ as above. Because one may be closed in $|X|$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But if $X$ is finite, they are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not second countable, as example 3 on page 9 (in Elements of Algebraic Topology by Munkres) shows: exercise 4 on page 14 remarks that this space is not even first countable at $(0,0)$, so certainly not second countable.

This simplex is the collection of $1$-simplices $\sigma_i$,$i=1,2,\ldots$ which are the line-segments from $(0,0)$ to $(1, \frac{1}{i})$.

Comment: yeah but in example 3 on page 9, $K$ is not locally finite. Actually I'm trying to prove the question 7. And I wanna use this Theorem: If locally compact Hausdorff space is second countable then it's metrizable. So, I need to justify first, whether an underlying space of a locally finite complex is second countable.

Comment: Aha. Well Lemma 4 of http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178245452 shows that $|K|$ is Hausdorff paracompact (always) and a locally compact simplical complex is locally metrisable, and so Smirnov's theorem says it's metrisable in the locally compact = locally finite case.

Comment: See also http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195570434

Comment: How did you justify that locally compact simplical complex is locally metrisable? And I can't find Smirnov's Theorem in your paper.

Comment: Every point is essentially in a finite union of metrisable simplices. Smirnov says that a locally metrisable paracompact Hausdorff space is metrisable.

Comment: Oh I see. I got it now. Thank you. Also thanks for your papers, it has lot of usefull lemmas and theorems.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38486/discussion-between-chen-m-ling-and-henno-brandsma).